# Webview shows error "Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail"

Tags: android, webview

My tablet Android version is 7.0 and Chrome version 62.0.3202.84.

When first run my webview app, debug window show

> Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail

RenderProcessGoneDetail is android 8.0 API

How do I prevent the error message?

```
11-28 13:23:13.133 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.eb>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.G(android.webkit.WebView, android.content.Context) (WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:323)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:636)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:724)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:792)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(int) (PhoneWindow.java:459)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.setContentView(int) (Activity.java:2548)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.himart.omni.himartomniapp.view.activity.WebViewActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (WebViewActivity.java:257)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6955)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.G(android.webkit.WebView, android.content.Context) (WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:323)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:636)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:724)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:792)
11-28 13:23:13.273 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(int) (PhoneWindow.java:459)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.setContentView(int) (Activity.java:2548)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.himart.omni.himartomniapp.view.activity.WebViewActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (WebViewActivity.java:257)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6955)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
11-28 13:23:13.274 28584-28584/com.himart.omni.himartomniapp I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Try to downgrade your SDK versions!
Target SDK 25
 buildtools versions 25
compileSdkversion 25

Comment: @MuhammadSaad downgrading is definitely not suitable solution. Any other option or suggestions?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: No problem with that: you can safely ignore it :-) Read the description of [issue #791099 on bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=791099)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It appears to be a bug, more details here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/android-webview-dev/m0EtO3IXNn0

> On N+ new ART logging appears to have been introduced letting app
>   developers know about certain binary compatibility problems in their
>   code. Unfortunately, this is triggering for some of the API-level
>   guarded code in WebView.
>
> One example is "Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;", which is triggered whenever
>   a recent version of WebView with O features is used on an N device.
>   This is harmless, but confusing and spammy to developers looking at
>   logcat.

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue on N devices? I am facing same thing.

Comment: It doesn't crash my app, and the app seems to work normally so I just ignore this issue.

Comment: Any update on this? I am getting this issue on every Android 7.0+ devices and the website doesn't load the page.

On Android 6.0 I don't have this crash and everything works fine.

Comment: Im looking for a solution, my app is crashing due to webview error.

Comment: @Karoly did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I had this issue because I’m the url I had a space . I had to encode the url to make it work:%20

Comment: @Karoly Ok thanks. But by url you mean external urls only or also local files url?

Comment: In file like index.hrml#alma.js

Answer (score 8):

There is a problem with Android after 7.0, but I managed to find a solution. For me it worked to follow [this tutorial](http://kosalgeek.com/webview-fragment-android-studio/).
In a summary the fragment should look like this:

```
public class WebFragment1 extends Fragment{
    public WebFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    WebView wvPage1;
    String url = "http://apptimist.studio";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_fragment1, container, false);
        wvPage1 = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.wvPage1);
        wvPage1.loadUrl(url);
        WebSettings settings = wvPage1.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvPage1.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        return v;
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I tried without those two lines, but it was not working, so I included them and it worked. Pay attention to add them

```
WebSettings settings = wvPage1.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

There is the notification that there might be a vulnerability to XSS attacks, you should be opening trusted websites preferably.

And here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kosalgeek.webviewfragment.WebFragment1">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvPage1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope that this will help someone as I spent a lot of time looking for the solution

Comment: Thanks! this is working for me! Do you think, that only adding https to the URL, will be ok? for `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` ?

Comment: I personally use HTTP link, but for a private server that we have control on. HTTPS is surely better option as it is encrypting the data and XSS is generally prevented. On the server side (if you control it) you should have also good sanitization and follow best practices.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Well, I ended adding the HTTPS to the url, as I have control over the server, so I hope this goes well haha! Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Apparently, https webpages are not loading correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `WebSettings#setSafeBrowsingEnabled(false)` in api level 26. It works for me

Refs: [WebSettings#setSafeBrowsingEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSafeBrowsingEnabled(boolean))

Comment: How can this setting solve a problem that occurs on N devices, when this API is only available at level 26, which is O??

Answer (score -1):

I had the same log message but the worst part is that it was opening chrome to load the page.
That was a problem since when the back button was pressed, the user was brought back to the activity with a blank page.

So what I did, is I just set the WebViewClient on the webView:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Now the error log is gone and the page is loading in the webview.

Hope this helps anyone!

Comment: No effect. The error occurs while the WebView is being created.