# Cordova website doesn't load fully

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I have my Android native project which has it's cordova SystemWebView init. 
Happens only on real device not on Emulator:
Works well on Android 6.0, but On Android 7.0+ devices the website doesn't load and I am getting this error message:

```
 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class

 java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.db>: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
 Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;

 03-16 18:45:03.913 
 com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) 
 (WebViewChromium.java:42)

Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.db>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;
at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:636)
at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
at void org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (SystemWebView.java:47)

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponse" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webview shows error "Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524032/webview-shows-error-didnt-find-class-android-webkit-renderprocessgonedetail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was not related to Cordova at all
Android 7.0+ started to replace the space charecter in the URL with %20 (encoded) which killed the JS side.

Comment: So any idea on how could I solve this situation? Or at least what should I suggest to my app users? In some devices my app doesn't even open.

Comment: I had to modify the JS code of mine , and decide / encode the url there