# MobileAds.initialize causes ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, admob

I'm using PlayServices and MobileAds v15.0.1

This call

```
MobileAds.initialize(activity, appIdAdmob);
```

Causes this error Log:

```
I art     : 
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.db>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;
  at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:636)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:532)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.u.<init>(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.at, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, java.lang.String, boolean, mt, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bn, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.w, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):1)
  at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):5)
  at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bs.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):23)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, mt, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bn, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.w, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):8)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.q.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, mt) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):7)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.z.run() ((null):5)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):4)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ao com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a(mt) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):17)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ak com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a() (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):27)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(java.lang.Object) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):4)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, boolean, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.e, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):55)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):4)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ax.a(java.lang.String, xk) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):55)
  at boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bc.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):42)
  at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:507)
  at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aiz.b(int, android.os.Parcel) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aqd.a(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.b.a) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aqt.a(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aqv) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.i.a(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.i$a) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.i.a(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
  at MobileAds.initialize(activity, appIdAdmob);
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
  at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:48)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:636)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:532)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.u.<init>(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.at, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, java.lang.String, boolean, mt, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bn, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.w, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):1)
  at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):5)
  at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bs.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):23)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, mt, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bn, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.w, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):8)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.q.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, mt) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):7)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.z.run() ((null):5)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):4)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ao com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a(mt) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):17)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ak com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a() (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):27)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(java.lang.Object) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):4)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, boolean, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.e, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):55)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.m, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):4)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ax.a(java.lang.String, xk) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):55)
  at boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bc.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):42)
  at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:507)
  at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aiz.b(int, android.os.Parcel) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aqd.a(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.b.a) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aqt.a(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.aqv) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.i.a(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.i$a) ((null):-1)
  at void com.google.android.gms.ads.i.a(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
  at MobileAds.initialize(activity, appIdAdmob);
```

This issue occurs only on Android 7.0 device. Is there a workaround or can this error just be ignored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webview shows error "Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524032/webview-shows-error-didnt-find-class-android-webkit-renderprocessgonedetail)